# Trying to set values in a dataframe - multiplying dataframe columns by a value

Tags: pandas

I am trying to multiple columns in a df called `mod.result` by a value `mod.adj_ratio` using the following:

```
 for col in PNL_COLS[:3]:
            mod.result[col]*=mod.adj_ratio
```

I am getting a

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:

    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have read the on line post I am assuming its because I am chaining slices together. As a result I have tried:

```
 for col in PNL_COLS[:3]:
            mod.result.loc[[:,col]]*=mod.adj_ratio
```

and also tried:

```
    for col in PNL_COLS[:3]:
             df1=mod.is_pnl[col]
             df2=df1*mod.adj_ratio
             mod.is_pnl[col]=df2
```

without success. What can I try next?

Comment: First off, this just a warning of behavior you probably didn't intend on happening anyway.

Comment: and mod.result is subset of other df ? adding .,copy